# ImportError Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having a serious problem trying to import Tensorflow. When I do it, I get the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Google Drive/Python/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.
```

---

I have VC 2015.

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow? From the error message it looks like you're using Python 3.6, but the official release only supports Python 3.5.

Comment: Had no idea about that, thank you sir! Will give it a try immediately

Comment: That was it. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was that I had Python 3.6, while Tensorflow only supports Python 3.5.